# Is it possible to change the precision in Compile?

Tags: compile, precision-and-accuracy

I'm using `Compile` to do some numerical calculation and I need high `Precision`. I was wondering if it is possible to change the precision in command `Compile` to some `$MinPrecision`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Compile` does not support arbitrary precision calculations.  It uses the CPU's native support for floating point arithmetic, which allows it to run fast, but also limits it to `$MachinePrecision` effective decimal digits (about 16 digits).

Comment: Thanks a lot. So. it means I should find other way to do my calculation.
Best,
Hesam

Comment: Though not quite obvious, this is actually mentioned in the **Details and Options** of the document of `Compile`: *The types handled by Compile are:  machine‐size integer, machine‐precision approximate real number (default), machine‐precision approximate complex number,  logical variable*.